# Firebase auth and sign out

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

My app uses both e-mail and Google Auth. The problem appears if the user signs out and tries logging in. App closes and, when clicked again, opens with the user logged in. If I press the back button from the login screen and exit the app, when launched again works as expected. 
Here is the code I use for signing out:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.getOut) {
        mFirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        DetachReadListener();
        finishAffinity();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SING_IN) {
        if (resultCode==RESULT_CANCELED) {
            finishAffinity();
        }
    }

}
```

Android Monitor shows no error so I don't have any clue on this. Please help me solve this bug.

Thank you!

My login code:

```
 public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

            FirebaseUser user = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

            if (user!=null) {

                 uid = user.getUid();

                if (user.getPhotoUrl()!=null) {
                    avatarurl = user.getPhotoUrl().toString();
                    RoundedBitmapDrawable drawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getApplicationContext().getResources(),getImageBitmap(avatarurl));
                    drawable.setCircular(true);
                    imgavatar.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                 //   imgavatar.setImageBitmap(getImageBitmap(avatarurl));
                } else
                    imgavatar.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_account_black_48dp);

                mUsername = user.getDisplayName();
                username.setText(mUsername);
                AttachReadListener();
                DatabaseReference usruid = usersref.child(uid).child("flag");

                usruid.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        while (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            pb.setContentView(R.layout.activity_progress_bar);
                            pb.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                            pb.show();
                        }
                        val = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            } else {
                startActivityForResult(
                        AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                                .setTheme(R.style.LoginTheme)
                                .setLogo(R.drawable.firstlogo)
                        .setAvailableProviders(Arrays.asList(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build(),new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build()))
                        .build(), RC_SING_IN

                );

            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Please give more detail code

Comment: What are you doing in `finishAffiinity` and `DetaisReadListener` methods? Further, please post your sign in code.

Comment: Hello and thank you! I have edited my post, by adding login code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you are using both e-mail and google sign in. So, if the user is signed in with e-mail method then use `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()`.
If the user is signed in using google sign in then sign out the user from both **Google Sign-In** and **Firebase** like:

```
 googleSignInClient.signOut().addOnCompleteListener(this,
            new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    // firebase sign out
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();                        

                    Intent intent = new Intent(SignOutActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();

                }
            });
```